# Merge FormGroups

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

Hello I have a question about formGroups or abstractControls in general

I create my FormGroup via a FormBuilder

```
createControl() {
 const group = this.fb.group({});
 this.fields.forEach(field => {
   if (field.type === 'button') {
     return;
   }
   const control = this.fb.control(
     {value: field.value, disabled: field.disabled},
     this.bindValidations(field.validations || [])
   );
   group.addControl(field.name, control);
 });
 return group;
}
```

I use the formbuilder when I want to create my dynamic forms.
Now that some values change some of the options of formcontrols change. My server sends me a new representation of the FormGroup. Is it possible to then create a new form via the formbuilder and merge her with my old formgroup ?

respone from server

```
{"formControls[
  {"name":"name","inputType":"text","disabled":false,"label":"Username","type":"input"},
  {"name":"gender","options":["Male","Female"],"label":"Gender","type":"radiobutton","value":"Male"},
  {"name":"country","options":
    [{"value":"Germany","key":"1"},{"value":"Germany","key":"2"}],
    "disabled":false,"label":"Country","type":"select","value":"UK"}],"name":"MyFirstForm"}
```

Comment: `My server sends me a new representation of the FormGroup.` Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

change a bit your function createControl

```
createControl(groupOld) {
   //then you can
   const group = groupOld|| this.fb.group({});
   ....and add all the fields of this.fields..
   ..you can use a if like
   if (!groupOld.get('field.value'))
       //add the field

   //or 
   const value=groupOld.value
   ...and after create the form use 
   group.patchVallue(value);
}
```

Comment: if my form already has a formcontrol from a field, but there is no value selected. the formgroup would add another one with the same name ?

Comment: NO. the controls of the formGroups must be different, it's the reason because before  `group.addControl(field.name, control);` you must checked `if group.get('field.name')==null)` prior to add it